# logic of running through 2 loops, comparing, updating and then removing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

```
List<SalesRecord> SalesRecords = new List<SalesRecord>();
while(sr.EndOfStrem)
{
    SalesRecord Sale = new SalesRecord();
    //assigns data to sale.pluid, sale,quantity, sale.subtotal
    SalesRecords.Add(Sale);  
}

foreach (SalesRecord _sale in SalesRecords)
{
    foreach (SalesRecord _matchingSale in SalesRecords)
    {
        if (_sale.PLUId == _matchingSale.PLUId)
        {
              _sale.Quantity = _sale.Quantity + _matchingSale.Quantity;
              _sale.Subtotal = _sale.Subtotal + _matchingSale.Subtotal;
              //SalesRecords.Remove(_matchingSale);
         }
     }
 }

 Console.WriteLine(SalesRecords.ToList());
```

this just outputs:

```
Synchroniser.SalesRecord,
Synchroniser.SalesRecord,
Synchroniser.SalesRecord,
Synchroniser.SalesRecord,
Synchroniser.SalesRecord,
Synchroniser.SalesRecord
etc..etc..etcc
```

I want to output the sales of saleRecords? id, quantity and subtotal?, for each record

**Also I've commneted out the remove line. because this throws the error: collection was modified: enumeration operation may not execute.**

Is my logic wrong?
what I was trying to do was

1. create a list.
2. run through a streamreader, every time it runs through add a 'sales'record and populate then add it to SalesRecords.
3. At the end of the streameder use 2 for loops to compare the loop, as there could be multiple records for the same pluId eg.

Input

```
 PLUId Quantity Subtotal
    1     4        4.00
    2     2        8.50
    3     7        3.90
    1     3        3.00
```

so at the end I would like the following outputed:

```
  PLUId Quantity Subtotal
    1     7        7.00
    2     2        8.50
    3     7        3.90
```

..please advise

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a `Dictionary` instead of adding duplicate items to a list and then removing them.

```
var SalesRecords = new Dictionary<int, SalesRecord>();
```

Inside the `while` loop, you could do a lookup:

```
var currentPLUId = // get the PLUId for the current record

if (SalesRecords.ContainsKey(currentPLUId))
{
    var sale = SalesRecords[currentPLUId];

    // increase the quantity, subtotal fields
}
else
{
    var sale = new SalesRecord();

    // set the quantity, subtotal fields

    SalesRecords.Add(currentPLUId, sale);
}
```

Also, your call to `Console.WriteLine(SalesRecords.ToList());` puts out bad data because you can't just pass an entire list to it and expect it'll know what to do with that. You can tell it specifically which values to display:

```
foreach (var sale in SalesRecords)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(
        sale.PLUId, " - " , sale.Quantity, " - ", sale.Subtotal);
```

Or you could override `ToString` in the SalesRecord class to display whatever you want, and then do:

```
foreach (var sale in SalesRecords)
    Console.WriteLine(sale);        // sale.ToString() is called
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use LINQ you could group your PLUId and Sum the quantity and subtotal in a new collection:

```
var qr = (from s1 in SalesRecords
           group s1 by s1.PLUId into g
           select new SalesRecord{ 
                        PLUId = g.Key ,
                        Quantity = g.Sum( m =>m.Quantity ) ,
                        Subtotal = g.Sum( m=> m.Subtotal) })
                        .ToList();
Console.WriteLine("PLUId Quantity Subtotal");  
foreach (var s in qr)
      Console.WriteLine("{0,7} {1,9} {2,9}",s.PLUId, s.Quantity, s.Subtotal);
```